# Get custom filed values using ajax in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Here is the scenario :

- There are several products in a category (Products means posts in a
  particular category)
- Each product (post) have several images (I managed it by adding
  custom fields)
- In the front end, Products will display all together
- On that page there will be a image slider in the footer
- Clicking on each product name, will change the slider images
  accordingly to the clicked product

So all i need is to get the custom field values corresponding to the clicked product. Is it possible to do this using AJAX request.? So that i can manage all this process without a post back.

Thanks.

Comment: Simple request a ajax call on click of the project name or put some code snipped and show us what you have tried??

Comment: Hi sumit, Thanks for the reply. I haven't tried anything yet. I am not getting a start point. All the thing i know is the "admin-ajax.php" is managing all the ajax requests. Can you please show a example ?

Comment: i don;t have exp in word press but i will find out something and will try to put some ccode snipped but you can try by simple calling a jqueyy function and the ajax request url is in your hand ,it is not neccesaay to use admin_ajax.php whaetever url you will give request must go to that page .Anyway hopefully some intelligent word press developer will help you for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy. Ofocourse thanks to Rajat Modi for the help in ajax. Here you go :

Add this to the functions.php in your template file :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/myajax.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); // jQuery will be included automatically
    // get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js'; // Inside a parent theme
    // get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js'; // Inside a child theme
    // plugins_url( '/js/script.js', __FILE__ ); // Inside a plugin
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' ); // ajax for logged in users
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' ); // ajax for not logged in users
    function ajax_action_stuff() 
    {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id']; // getting variables from ajax post
        // doing ajax stuff
        $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
        $imageurlset = $custom_fields['images'];
        $urlstring = $imageurlset[0];
        $imageurl = explode(',', $urlstring);
        //update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_key', 'meta_value');
        exit(json_encode($imageurl)); // stop executing script
    }
```

Create and add the following code to "/js/script.js" :

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('.prduct_name').click(function () {
        $('.spcl_content').find('.prduct_name').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        var ithis = $(this);
        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'ajax_action',
            post_id: ithis.attr("id")
        }, function(data) {
            var number_of_images = data.length;
            //console.log(data);
            var image_link="";

            for(var i=0; i<number_of_images; i++)
                {
                     var image_url = data[i];
                     image_link = image_link+'<li><a href="'+image_url+'" rel="scroller" target="temp_win"><img src="'+image_url+'"/></a></li>'


                }

            //console.log(image_link); // alerts 'ajax submitted'
            var starting='<div class="wt-scroller"><div class="prev-btn"></div><div class="slides"><ul class="slider_mania">';
            var ending='</ul></div><div class="next-btn"></div><div class="lower-panel"></div></div>';
            var total=starting+image_link+ending;
            //console.log(total);
            $(".container_carol").html(total).fadeIn("slow");

        },"json");

    return false;

    });
```

I hope it is clear now. Thanks again for the reply my friend. Have a great day. :)

Comment: My scenario is little different then you. I have a question on this link--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416409/wordpress-custom-metabox-input-value-with-ajax Can you answer me please

Answer (score 2):

I haven't experience in wordpress but I can show you the example of of AJAX.

As far as I know that you have to do call ajax function on the click of related post or product like this.

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("#PRODCUTID").click(function () {
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "POST"
         ,url :"YOUR_URL_ON_WHICH_YOU_PUT_LOGIC_TO_FETCH_IDS_FOR_SLIDER"
         ,data :"CLICKED_PRODUCT_ID="+CLICKED_PRODUCT_ID // this the variable which will be posted and will find it (particular URL which you passed) on the controller action or in view file
         ,success : function(data){               
            //YOUR CODE HERE WHICH IS REPLACING PRODUCT ID  
         }
         ,beforeSend: function(html){
          //some kind of loader or text mean while data is waiting for the response
                },
          });
      })
})
</script>
```

Hope this will help and feel free to ask anything for AJAx request.