# Wordpress change post title before publish

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress 3.5, I create a custom post type called order with title supports only.
Now i want that when this order will publish the title text will be `order-#ID` , (here ID will be the post ID that going to be publish) nothing else if user write something in title it will not publish it just save with value like `order-#23` .

Another thing is any other way to hide title input (i don't wanna show title and editor) but save its value when it publish as like `order-#265`.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hook it at [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and then update the database to reflect the change in title.

Note that I didn't test the code but it should be something like that:

```
function save_title( $post_id ){
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_title' =>  'order-#' . $post_id ), array( 'ID' => $post_id ) ); 
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_title');
```

Comment: Can you please answer my another question. Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416409/wordpress-custom-metabox-input-value-with-ajax

Comment: I can't answer anything better than what [brasofilo said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14418553/1370034) :)

Comment: thx, rrikesh ;) :::: @zxprince, can't you even provide some feedback there? You know, someone spends **time and brains** and you don't even upvote :/

Comment: :D Sorry brasofilo. i am trying your code... now it working .. thank you